# What is null coalescing assignment ??= operator in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, php-7.4

I've just seen a video about upcoming PHP 7.4 features and saw new `??=` operator. I already know the `??` operator. How's this different?

Comment: Short and sweet: `$foo = $foo ?? 'bar'` can be shortened to `$foo ??= 'bar'`;

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From the [docs](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/null_coalesce_equal_operator):

> Coalesce equal or ??=operator is an assignment operator. If the left parameter is null, assigns the value of the right paramater to the left one. If the value is not null, nothing is done.

**Example:**

```php
// The folloving lines are doing the same
$this->request->data['comments']['user_id'] = $this->request->data['comments']['user_id'] ?? 'value';
// Instead of repeating variables with long names, the equal coalesce operator is used
$this->request->data['comments']['user_id'] ??= 'value';
```

So it's basically just a shorthand to assign a value if it hasn't been assigned before.

Comment: it's not 100% exact that the 2 lines are doing "the same", in the second case the left-hand side is only evaluated once, so it's more efficient

Comment: *'If the left parameter is null, assigns (...)'*. Don't you think it should be corrected to: *'If the left parameter is null **OR is not set**, assigns (...)'* 
?

Answer (score 9):

Null coalescing assignment operator chaining:

```
$a = null;
$b = null;
$c = 'c';

$a ??= $b ??= $c;

print $b; // c
print $a; // c
```

[Example at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BBJZE)

Comment: That example can be handled easily by the null coalescing operator `??` because all variables are defined.  The point of the null coalescing *assignment* operator is that it will work with undefined variables. So you can remove the first two lines which assign nulls to $a and $b and the code will still work.

Comment: This comes right out of hell but you helped me to understand messy code I can now clean up :D

Answer (score 8):

The null coalescing assignment operator is a shorthand way of assigning the result of the null coalescing operator.

An example from the official [release notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php#migration74.new-features.core.null-coalescing-assignment-operator):

```
$array['key'] ??= computeDefault();
// is roughly equivalent to
if (!isset($array['key'])) {
    $array['key'] = computeDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Example [Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php):

```
$array['key'] ??= computeDefault();
// is roughly equivalent to
if (!isset($array['key'])) {
    $array['key'] = computeDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to initialize variables during a loop's first iteration. But beware!

```
$reverse_values = array();
$array = ['a','b','c']; // with [NULL, 'b', 'c'], $first_value === 'b'
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $first_value ??= $value; // won't be overwritten on next iteration (unless 1st value is NULL!)
  $counter ??= 0; // initialize counter
  $counter++;
  array_unshift($reverse_values,$value);
}
// $first_value === 'a', or 'b' if first value is NULL
// $counter === 3
// $reverse_values = array('c','b','a'), or array('c','b',NULL) if first value is null
```

If the first value is `NULL`, then `$first_value` will be initialized to `NULL` and then overwritten by the next non-`NULL` value. If the array has a lot of `NULL` values, `$first_value` will end up either as `NULL` or the first non-`NULL` after the last `NULL`. So this seems like a terrible idea.

I would still prefer doing something like this mainly because it's more clear, but also because it works with `NULL` as an array value:

```
$reverse_values = array();
$array = ['a','b','c']; // with [NULL, 'b', 'c'], $first_value === NULL
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  $counter++;
  if($counter === 1) $first_value = $value; // does work with NULL first value
  array_unshift($reverse_values,$value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can roughly be translated as ***"$a defaults to $b"***, like this:

```php
$page ??= 1;            //  If page is not specified, start at the beginning
$menu ??= "main";       //  Default menu is the main menu
$name ??= "John Doe";   //  Name not given --> use John Doe
```

A long-awaited tool in the world of PHP.
Before PHP 7.4, we did this with a function:

```php
function defaultOf(&$var, $value) {
    if(is_null($var)) $var=$value;
}

// Now the 3 statements above would look like:

defaultOf( $page, 1 );
defaultOf( $menu, "main" );
defaultOf( $name, "John Doe" );
```

(I still use it because it's more readable.)

Answer (score 0):

Example use case for this Null Coalescing Assignment operator in 2024:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Pages;

use App\Entities\User;

class WelcomePage extends AbstractPage
{
    protected User $user;
    
    protected function setUser(User $user): static
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this;
    }

    protected function getUser(): User
    {
        return $this->user ??= new User("Anonymous"); // Null Coalescing Assignment
    }

    public function display(): string
    {
        return $this->getUser()->loggedIn() ?
            "<h1>Welcome {$this->getUser()->name}! :D</h1>" :
            '<h1>Welcome! :)</h1><a href="/login">log in</a>';
    }
}
```

In this example, `App\Pages\WelcomePage` is an extension of the `App\Pages\AbstractPage` class which contains all of the common functions of pages in our app.

This particular page needs to get the current `User` as an object and display the name, but only if logged in. This page is not responsible for managing the login state of the user - that's handled elsewhere. The `getUser()` function is going to try to read the `$user` property of our class, but if the property is not initialised, because we haven't called `setUser()` yet, it will first initialise it with `new User("Anonymous")` and then return the value of the property. Subsequent calls to `getUser()` will not need to initialise the property.

We can use this `WelcomePage` class later in some other file like this for anonymous users:

```php
$page = new WelcomePage();
echo $page->display();
```

Or like this for logged-in users:

```php
$page = new WelcomePage();
echo $page->setUser($loggedInUser)->display();
```

To extend this further, we could move `$user` and its getter and setter into the `AbstractPage` so that all of our pages can `extend` it and have `$user` initialised automatically, but only when we want to use it and not more than once.

If we didn't have this operator, we would have to rewrite this function:

```php
    protected function getUser(): User
    {
        if (!isset($this->user)) {
            $this->user = new User("Anonymous");
        }
        return $this->user;
    }
```

Or use a simple getter:

```php
    protected function getUser(): User
    {
        return $this->user; // can cause an error if not initialised
    }
```