# What is double question mark equal?

Tags: javascript

What does `??=` do in JavaScript?

```
keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] ??= {}, obj)[last] = value
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`??=` is similar to [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) introduced as [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) implemented like other languages: [php example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102708/what-is-null-coalescing-assignment-operator-in-php-7-4). The logical nullish assignment is introduced in ES12 (ECMAScript 2022).

> The logical nullish assignment (x ??= y) operator only assigns if x is nullish (null or undefined).

Example:

```
let foo = null;
let bar = "Give me a beer!";

foo ??= bar;
```

`foo ?? (foo = bar)` is the equivalent of the above expression. The variable `foo` gets assigned the variable `bar` only if `foo` is `null` or `undefined`. In this example, foo becomes "Give me a beer!". If we replace `let foo = null` with `let foo = "I don't need a beer!", the assignment does not happen. The variable foo stays "I don't need a beer!".

The equivalent code with an `if statement` is as follows:

```
let foo = null;
let bar = "Give me a beer!";

if (foo == null || foo == undefined) {
    foo = bar;
}
```

It does not check for other falsy values. It only checks for `null` and `undefined`.

---

So, in your example of code `o[k]` assigns an empty object `{}` when `o[k]` value results `null` or `undefined`.