# Difference between PHP ??, ?:, and ??=

Tags: php

Something I'm not exactly clear on, how does `??`, `?:`, and `??=` differ in PHP?

I know `??=` was only added in PHP7.4.
I also know that `??` is for checking null values, but `?:` also seems to check for null values, so I'm not entirely sure of the difference.

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59102708/what-is-null-coalescing-assignment-operator-in-php-7-4

Comment: @GuidoFaecke I'm asking about the difference between the 3 not singularly `??=` That gives me a partial answer about `??=` though. I'm still quite confused about `??` and `?:` though.

Comment: The first answer in the post above explains it...anyway `?:` is your typical ternary operator, similar to an if/else. `??` as in `$test = $data ?? false` checks against all, aka. null coalesce. `??=` is another shorthand for null-coalesce as in `$data ??= false`. In this case you are setting default values to `$data` if `$data` is `null`.

Comment: Also maybe see here [Elvis-Operator vs Null Coalescing Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-elvis-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Elvis operator vs null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-elvis-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Comment: @Aranxo that question did not solely answer this question, I was asking about all three, not just those two.

Comment: Sorry, I was flagging your question as already answered for reviewing by the admins. For the first time I did such thing ever. I did't know this will create another answer. So I basically answered you twice the same. :-/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To combine all answers already made in former questions. With `??` you check for existence and not being `null`, with `?:` you check for `true/false`.

```
$result = $a ?? $b
```

is the same as:

```
if (isset($a) && !is_null($a)) {
    $result = $a;
} else {
    $result = $b;
}
```

The `??=` is a shortcut for `??` and it works like `.=` or `+=` as well, which means you can shorten

```
$a = $a ?? $b;
```

to

```
$a ??= $b;
```

The `?:` is a shortcut for the ternary operator which is also a shortcut:

```
if ($a) {
    $result = $a;
} else {
    $result = $b;
}
```

is the same as:

```
$result = $a ? $a : $b;
```

is the same as:

```
$result = $a ?: $b;
```

You could both describe as: The first operand is the value to check, and if this one is useful, take it, if not, take the second as default.

You can concatenate them like this one:

```
$user = $_POST['user'] ?? $_SESSION['user'] ?? $_COOKIE['user'] ?? '';
```

Which means something like: If you get the username in the POST array because of just logging in, fine, take it, if not, see whether the user is already logged on and in the session, if yes, take it, if not, maybe we have a user in the Cookies (checked the "remember me" checkbox while last login), and if this fails also, well, then leave it empty.

Of course you have to check the password too. ;-)

Edit: I use the `?:` operator very often to ensure that I have a certain datatype in a variable. There are a lot PHP functions that give back maybe a string or an array if successful, but `false` if some error occured. Instead of having false as result, having the empty string or empty array is more consistent. As example, `scandir` should give back an array, but gives back `false` if an error occures. So you can do this:

```
$files = scandir('/some/random/folder') ?: [];
```

Then `$files` will always be an array, even if `scandir` fails. Well, then it's an empty array, but maybe better than checking later against `false`. In fact, we already did it with very low effort. Then you can use a `foreach` loop without some wrapping `if`. If `scandir` failed, the array is empty and the loop will just do nothing.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. It's very informative. Additionally, you described the importance of using ternary operator instead of null coalescence to avoid setting unexpected data type values or pitfall due to dynamic return value in case of ?? operator.